# Extracting an image ID from an image path

Tags: python

how can I extract images id from image path.
just want to take 10877 from this path `/content/gdrive/MyDrive/new/batch/aligned_10877nationalIdFront.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

path = "/content/gdrive/MyDrive/new/batch/aligned_10877nationalIdFront.png"

# It will return the first match only
x = re.search("[0-9]+", path)
print(x.group())


# or in case if there are multiple sets...
x = re.findall("[0-9]+", path)
print(x[0]) # x[0] for the first, x[1] for the second, and so on


# If "aligned_" is always there you may also do
x = re.findall("aligned_([0-9]+)", path)
print(x[0])
```

Please have a look at the [re library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). It's very useful for many applications.